# One of expo_runtime_version or expo_sdk_version must be defined in the Android app manifest

Tags: react-native, expo

After ejecting from expo, my app is working great in a dev environment, but on creating any production build with for example `./gradlew assembleRelease` it was instantly crashing on startup with this error on android:

`One of expo_runtime_version or expo_sdk_version must be defined in the Android app manifest`.

Answer (score 0):

TLDR; Run `expo build:android` first

I had a monorepo with multiple projects, I manually made a new react native init without expo and got that working. But I had 2 other apps with the same error, and after accidentaly building one of them with `expo build:android`, I noticed `./gradlew bundleRelease` started to work perfectly. Seem also in my git diff that it generated a bunch of native code, probably necessary for it to run.